How can I trigger re-render of an element (which uses state) in a callback function?
I am currently using React and have run into a problem regarding states.
Consider a callback function testComponent, which, when a button is pressed, renders a new component each time.
Within this component, there will be select and input elements, and based on what is selected, the input element must also update.
The select element will display the name of the object, and the input element will display its ID.
All of the selectedOptions will start off with a default value of options[0] which happens in a useEffect.
This is a recreation of my problem just using the word test instead so that its easier to understand (less context needed). The idea is that every time the select element changes, it should also update the input value.
export default function CreateTestComponent() {
  const options: any[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Test 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Test 2",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Test 3"
    }
  ]

  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<any[]>([options[0]]);
  const [testComponentIndex, setTestComponentIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [components, setComponents] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setComponents([testComponent(0)]);
    setTestComponentIndex((old) => old + 1);

    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      setSelectedOptions((old) => {
        const temp = [...old];
        temp[i] = options[0];
        return temp
      })
    }
  }, [])

  const testComponent = (index: number) => {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-5" id={`${index}`}>
        <select
          onChange={((e) => {
            const id = e.target.value;
            setSelectedOptions((old) => {
              const temp = [...old]
              temp[index] = options.filter((option) => option.id == id)[0];
              return temp;
            })
          })}>
          {options.map((option, index: number) => {
            return (
              <option key={index} value={option.id}>
                {option.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <input readOnly value={selectedOptions[index].id} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => {
        setTestComponentIndex((old) => old + 1)
        setComponents([...components, testComponent(testComponentIndex)]);
      }} className="bg-black text-white rounded px-3 py-1">
        Add a Component
      </button>
      <div>
        <h1>Component testing!</h1>
        <div>
          <ul className="list-none">
            {components.map((component: any, index: number) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <div className="flex flex-row gap-5">
                    {component}
                  </div>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

This code will work in a .tsx file.
As you can see, the state is updating, but the input element doesn't update. I have done an annoying amount of research trying to figure out what is happening, and I am pretty sure that because it is inside a callback function in which the state is not continuously updated (which would, in turn, trigger a component rerender).
I tried doing a bunch of things to get around this obstacle. Namely, I tried useRef, but it doesn't have the capability of rerendering, which only useState appears to do.
I went through a bunch of other things but none of them got around this problem because none of them combatted the problem that is that the state is not the same outside versus inside the callback function.
If there is no way around having an up-to-date state within a callback function, what are some other alternatives I could try so that I could still have the ability of pressing a button and generating a new instance of a component each time?

You are storing JSX into your React state which leads to stale Javascript Closures. You should only store your data into state then map it to JSX when rendering.

I'm sorry, but what do you mean? What data should I store into state and then map when rendering?

Store whatever data represents your "state", i.e. whatever it is that represents the UI you wish to render. Based on your code it appears the state should be the options, or arrays of options, you are rendering.

You are storing JSX into your React state which leads to stale Javascript Closures. You should only store your data into state then map it to JSX when rendering. You are also over-complicating the logic a bit with the multiple states to represent the "data" and what is added, etc. It can be reduced to a single state.
Example Refactor:

Move the static options data outside the React tree
You are using Typescript, so you really ought to use it and create useful types/interfaces
Use a single selectedOptions state that is the array of objects with id and name properties you are rendering.
Add a GUID property to the data so they are always uniquely identifiable
Use the state updates to shallow copy the current state that you are updating and returning for the next state value
When adding new "components" create a new data object that represents the component/selected option you want to render

import { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

interface Option {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface SelectedOption extends Option {
  _id: string;
}

const options: Option[] = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Test 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Test 3" },
];

const createOption = (): SelectedOption => ({
  _id: nanoid(),
  ...options[0],
});

function CreateTestComponent() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<SelectedOption[]>([
    createOption(),
  ]);

  const renderOptions = (option: SelectedOption) => {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-5" id={`${option._id}`}>
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            const id = Number(e.target.value);
            setSelectedOptions((selectedOptions) =>
              selectedOptions.map((selectedOption) =>
                selectedOption._id === option._id
                  ? { ...selectedOption, id }
                  : selectedOption
              )
            );
          }}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
              {option.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input readOnly value={option.id} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedOptions((selectedOptions) =>
            selectedOptions.concat(createOption())
          );
        }}
        className="bg-black text-white rounded px-3 py-1"
      >
        Add a Component
      </button>
      <div>
        <h1>Component testing!</h1>
        <div>
          <ul className="list-none">
            {selectedOptions.map((option: SelectedOption) => {
              return (
                <li key={option._id}>
                  <div className="flex flex-row gap-5">
                    {renderOptions(option)}
                  </div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


Ohhh I see! This makes a lot of sense! You are mapping the array of selected options, and then rendering the component instead of what I was doing which was mapping the components (which were within a stale state) to render them. This is great, thank you very much for your help!
